# XSLT Parent select based on current node name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<field_x_position>
  <en is_array="true">
    <value>60</value>
  </en>
  <de is_array="true">
    <value>70</value>
  </de>
</field_x_position>

<field_background_image>
  <de is_array="true">
    <filename>filename_de.png</filename>
  </de>
  <en is_array="true">
    <filename>filenmae_en.png</filename>
  </en>
</field_background_image>
```

I try to re write it an get the following result

```
<backgroundImgage>
  <en x="60">filename_en.png</en>
  <de x="70">filename_de.png</de>
</backgroundImage>
```

Since there could be added more languages I need to loop over those. How can I select the matching value of the corresponding  element since name(.) in a XPath expression isn't working of course.

```
<xsl:element name="bgImage">
  <xsl:for-each select="field_background_image/*">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
      <xsl:attribute name="x">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../field_x_position/name(.)/item/value"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="item/filename"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is this (Note that there is no `item` element in your XML, so I have also removed this from the expression)

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../field_x_position/*[name() = current()/name()]/value"/>
```

Alternatively make use of a variable to slightly simplify it. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="bgImage">
            <xsl:for-each select="field_background_image/*">
                <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()" />
                <xsl:element name="{$name}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="x">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../field_x_position/*[name() = $name]/value"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [XSLT's built-in **key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="x" match="field_x_position/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <backgroundImage>
        <xsl:for-each select="field_background_image/*">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:attribute name="x">
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('x', name())/value"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </backgroundImage>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```